# White Spots on the screen when i get info from DB

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

i need some help,

this is what happen to me when i get data from my DB.

i dont know why this happen but if someone ever Encountered this topic and can help me i will thank him very much.

[image]

Comment: I have not seen anything like this for a very long time, but in my past experience, this is likely caused by a problem with a driver for your video card.

Comment: Is there any Issue with your computer or browser

Answer (score 0):

i find the answer, is a new chrome update.

if is happening to someone what you need to do is go to setting in chrome,

go all the way down until you see the **System** section,

[image]

there you can see i turn off the second option **"Use hardware acceleration when available"**.

this what caused the white spot's on the screen.